# Boolean function within an range?

Tags: python, pandas, function, boolean, range

I am trying to code a boolean function in which I can see if a modal score lives within the range of a real score.

```
 df['match'] = np.where(df['real_score'] + 0.5 >= df['modal_score']>= df['real_score'] - 0.5 , 'yes', 'no')
```

and

```
 df['match'] = np.where(df['modal_score']>= df['real_score']-0.5 and df['modal_score']<= df['real_score']+0.5, 'yes', 'no')
```

However this is not working. This is the error message I get : ''The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().''

Answer (score 0):

I was staring at your code and didn't see anything wrong so I went and tried it out *step by step*.

The problem lies in the chaining of the comparison. Apparently, this doesn't work for pandas DataFrames.

So you'll have to write your check either as a single comparison (e.g. using `abs(df['real_score'] - df['model_score']) <= 0.5` )

Ore you use two comparison and combine them with a logical and. But the `and` keyword doesn't work here either because that wants to just directly compare two booleans. Instead of the `and` you can use the `&` operator; make sure to use correct parentheses in this case:

```py
df['match'] = np.where( (df['modal_score']>= df['real_score']-0.5) & (df['modal_score']<= df['real_score']+0.5), 'yes', 'no')
```